# ASP.NET Server Unique Machine Identity

Tags: .net, license-key, web-farm

I need a unique key, or serial number of the computer or .asp.net application of the running server machine.

I will use this unique identifier for licensing purpose.

I am able to get 4byte serial number of the harddisk(of a webfarm), but maybe there is a longer id that I can get easily?

Is there any Windows ID, GUID, Machine Key or Application ID belongs to a specific computer/server that I can get easily with .NET library?